# Prevent Visual Studio to auto correct this

Tags: visual-studio-2013, dust.js, autocorrect

I have the following line:

```
<input id="cbField{$idx}" 
   type="checkbox" value="{ID}"
  {?checked}checked="checked"{Checked}"/>
<label for="cbField{$idx}">{Name}</label>
```

`{?checked}` is wrong, it should be `{?Checked}` with a Capital C.

When I copy 'Checked' and past it on 'checked', VS "correct" them both to 'checked'.

I work with dust.js so I'm not writing 100% "right of the bat" valid HTML and I'd like to prevent visual studio to make any single change to what I type

How can this be done?

Comment: I looked in VS settings and didn't find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it, it's in HTML/... Advanced : Format on paste.

Comment: Doesn't it change acordly to the VS version?
"Text Editor / HTML / Advanced" on min

Answer (score 1):

```
Tools / Options / Text Editor / HTML / Advanced / Format on past
```

On my VS version

Comment: @xDaevax I noticed now that I also have a HTML (WebForms) that is the same as your image. (VS web 13)